# How to use this library in android for Video Recording

Tags: android, android-video-player, vine

I am developing an Android App for recording video and sending to server. Also video must be recorded only on Touch of Record button. I have googled and got this library in the below link but I don't know how to use it in my project. This is the first time am going to use a library in a project. I have enable in my properties but don't know to use this functionality in my app. Please help me or suggest a tutorial.

https://github.com/sourab-sharma/TouchToRecord

Answer (score -1):

I have just unchecked the Library option from Properties and used it as a package in my project. Its really a silly question. But the worked great

Comment: @navya i am using the same and its working for me if you want any clarifications let me.

Comment: @MuraliGanesan its device issue check with any other device, if not possible in FFMpegActivity comment mPreview line and check